Embed an Excel File as a table within Word Doc with Python
I want to embed an Excel object within a Word document such that it shows up as a table within the doc, but is actually not a table - it is a linked Excel object. I want to achieve this with Python since I am generating the entire document on Python using libraries like docx-mailmerge.
I see that this can be done with pywin32, however, the catch is that I am trying to do this embedding for a streamlit app. Since streamlit runs on a Linux server, pywin32 cannot be deployed for the job.
I am unable to find any other libraries that can allow me to do OLE in python for Linux.
Would greatly appreciate help here since this is for a really important project. Thanks!

Check this out: Python: Insert or Extract OLE Objects in Word
